# accessing github in powershell/cmd resolves to localhost in windows10

Tags: router, vpn, powershell, proxy, cmd.exe

So I live in China and am using shadowsocksR on my router to bypass the Great firewall. Today when i try to update flutter using the powershell in VScode the powershell gives the error

"fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git/': Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 1080: Connection refused".

Seems like something make github resolve to localhost. Later I used both the terminal and powershell to ping google found out that they can't access any websites banned by the Great Firewall. So it seems like the proxy on my router failed to work. But the proxy does work on IE, Chrome, and any other devices that are connected to my router. The powershell and github was working fine like two weeks ago. Now I feel very desperate and thanks in advance!